# $f\in L^{1}[0,1]$ Show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{\frac{1}{n}}dx = m(\left\{ {x:f(x)\neq 0}\right\} )$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory, lp-spaces

The following is from a Sample Exam question I am studying from, and the question  has stumped me.

$$f\in L^{1}[0,1]$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{\frac{1}{n}}dx = m(\left\{ {x:f(x)\neq 0}\right\} )$$

What I think:from below:
I set $A=\{x:f(x)\neq 0\} )  $
Then
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}|f(x)|^{\frac{1}{n}}dx \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{\frac{1}{n}}dx$

When I take the limit both sides I get that required lower bound.

from above I get 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{\frac{1}{n}}dx \leq 1$$

any insight would be appreciated.
My Texing skills are not great, but the above sums up the best of my attempts so far.
Thank you

Comment: How did you conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 |f(x)|^{1/n}dx \leq 1$?

Comment: Have you evaluated $\lim_{n \to \infty} |f(x)|^{1/n}$?

Comment: I evaluated the integral to be  |f(x)|^1/n *m([0,1]), then took the limit, which gave me 1*1=1 for the upper bound.

Comment: You evaluated the integral and the result was a function of $x$? How can that be?

Comment: I suggest that you evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}|f(x)|^{1/n}$. It should be clear what to do once you have that answer.

Comment: Sorry, I took |f(x)|<t for some t between [0,||f||infinity],

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion regarding switching limits, I think I have it now.

Comment: Yes, the key observation is that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}|f(x)|^{1/n} = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if }f(x) \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{ if }f(x) = 0 \\ \end{cases}$$So interchanging the limit and the integral gives you what you want. The dominated convergence theorem justifies the interchange, as the answer by Dr. MV nicely demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $n>1$ we have for $f(x)\ne 0$

$$
|f(x)|^{1/n}\le
\begin{cases}
|f(x)|&,|f(x)|\ge 1\\\\
1&,|f(x)|<1 
\end{cases}$$

Since $|f(x)|^{1/n}\le \max(1,|f(x)|)$, and since $f\in L^1[0,1]$ the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 |f(x)|^{1/n}\,dx=\int_0^1 \lim_{n\to \infty}|f(x)|^{1/n}\,dx=m\{x: f(x)\ne 0\}$$